# If $x,y$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}$ and $x>0$ then there is a positive integer $n$ s.t. $nx > y$

Tags: real-analysis

Im reading a proof about this 
The proof is here.

Let $A$ be the set of all $nx$, where $n$ runs through the positive integers.
If $nx \le y$, then $y$ would be an upper bound of $A$.

(start confused)
But then $A$ has a least upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$.

(why? I know there is a theorem
There exists an ordered field $\mathbb{R}$ which has the least-upper-bound property.
What is this mean?)

Put $a = \sup A$. Since $x>0$, $a-x < a$, and $a-x$ is not an upper bound of $A$.
Hence $a-x < mx$ for some positive integer $m$. (why $mx$ is greater then $a-x$? what property is this.)
But then $a < (m+1)x$ where $(m+1)x$ is an element of $A$, which is impossible, since $a$ is an upper bound of $A$.

Comment: Is this R any ring, or is this $\Bbb R$, the field of reals?

Comment: Sorry about that is a Real number field. I don know how to type that symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming we are talking about the real numbers). For your first confusion part (A has a Least Upper Bound), what does the Completeness Property of the Real Numbers state about sets that are bounded above?

For your second confusion part ($a-x$ not being an upper bound $\Longrightarrow a-x<mx$ for some $m$), what is the definition of an upper bound of a set? What is the negation of that definition?

Comment: oh ya.. I get it! thank you very much with your guide. I like the way you teach.